# Is there a way of copying a JPanel's Graphic2D instance to make a Graphic2D for a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, file, save, bufferedimage

I have a JPanel which displays a graph using the Graphic2D. This works fine. I now want to be able to save the graph to a file. So far the only way I can get this to work is create a BufferedImage and everything I write to the JPanels Graphic2D object I write to the Graphic2D object belonging to the BufferedImage and then doing a PrintAll from the BufferedImage.
So I have code like the following:

```
    g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(fontSize));
    g.drawString(text, xPos, yPos);
    g.setFont(saveFont);
    bG.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(fontSize));
    bG.drawString(text, xPos, yPos);
    bG.setFont(saveFont);
```

where g is the Graphic2D object of the JPanel
and bG is the Graphic2D object of the BufferedImage

Surely this can't be the best way of doing this. Is there a way of using the Graphic2D object belonging to the JPanel to produce the Graphic2D object for the BufferedImage?

Comment: Great! That should have been an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd extract a method, say `paintGraph(Graphics2D g)` that paints the graph. Then you invoke it from two locations. Once from your `JPanel`'s `paintComponent(..)` method, and once in your "saveToFile" method, using your `BufferedImage`'s `Graphics2D` instance.

You might need a `Dimension` as a second parameter to your method, which is either the size of your panel or your image, if your graph drawing code is resizeable.

In code:

```
void paintGraph(Graphics2D g, Dimension size) {
    g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(fontSize));
    g.drawString(text, xPos, yPos);
    g.setFont(saveFont);
    // ...etc
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    paintGraph((Graphics2D) g, getSize());
}

void saveToFile(File f) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g = image.createGaphics();
    paintGraph(g, new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", f);
}
```